# usage differences between _variant_t, COleVariant, CComVariant, and VARIANT and using SAFEARRAY variations

Tags: c++, com, ado, atl, variant

I am investigating several Visual Studio 2015 C++ project types which use ADO to access an SQL Server database. The simple example performs a select against a table, reads in the rows, updates each row, and updates the table.

The MFC version works fine. The Windows console version is where I am having a problem updating the rows in the recordset. The `update()` method of the recordset is throwing a COM exception with the error text of:

```
L"Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal."
```

with an `HRESULT` of `0x800a0cc1`.

In both cases I am using a standard ADO recordset object defined as;

```
_RecordsetPtr       m_pRecordSet;   // recordset object
```

In the MFC version, the function to update the current row in the recordset is:

```
HRESULT CDBrecordset::UpdateRow(const COleVariant vPutFields, COleVariant vValues)
{
    m_hr = 0;
    if (IsOpened()) {
        try {
            m_hr = m_pRecordSet->Update(vPutFields, vValues);
        }
        catch (_com_error &e) {
            _bstr_t bstrSource(e.Description());
            TCHAR *description;
            description = bstrSource;
            TRACE2("  _com_error CDBrecordset::UpdateRow %s  %s\n", e.ErrorMessage(), description);
            m_hr = e.Error();
        }
    }

    if (FAILED(m_hr))
        TRACE3(" %S(%d): CDBrecordset::UpdateRow()  m_hr = 0x%x\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, m_hr);
    return  m_hr;
}
```

This function is called by using two `COleSafeArray` objects composed into a helper class to make it easier to specify the column names and values to be updated.

```
// Create my connection string and specify the target database in it.
// Then connect to SQL Server and get access to the database for the following actions.
CString  ConnectionString;
ConnectionString.Format(pConnectionStringTemp, csDatabaseName);

CDBconnector x;
x.Open(_bstr_t(ConnectionString));

// Create a recordset object so that we can pull the table data that we want.
CDBrecordset y(x);

//  ....... open and reading of record set deleted.

MyPluOleVariant thing(2);

thing.PushNameValue (SQLVAR_TOTAL, prRec.lTotal);
thing.PushNameValue (SQLVAR_COUNTER, prRec.lCounter);

hr = y.UpdateRow(thing.saFields, thing.saValues);
```

Because the Windows Console version is not using MFC, I am running into some definition issues which appear to be due to ATL COM class `CComSafeArray` being a template.

In the MFC source, `COleSafeArray` is a class derived from `tagVARIANT` which is a `union` that is the data structure for a `VARIANT`. However in ATL COM, `CComSafeArray` is a template that I am using as `CComSafeArray<VARIANT>` which seems reasonable.

However when I try to use a variable defined with this template, a class `CDBsafeArray` derived from `CComSafeArray<VARIANT>`, I get the following compilation error at the point where I call `m_pRecordSet->Update()`:

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "const CDBsafeArray" to "const _variant_t" exists
```

`_variant_t` seems to be a wrapper class for `VARIANT` and there does not seem to be a conversion path between `CComSafeArray<VARIANT>` and `_variant_t` however there is a conversion path between `COleSafeArray` and `_variant_t`.

What I have tried is to specify the `m_psa` member of the class which is a `SAFEARRAY` of type `VARIANT` and this compiles however I see the COM exception above when testing the application. Looking in the object with the debugger, the object specifying the fields to be updated appears to be correct.

So it appears I am mixing incompatible classes. What would be a `SAFEARRAY` wrapper class that will work with `_variant_t`?

Comment: Something like this should work: `_variant_t var; var.parray = myarray.Detach(); var.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;`. Where `myarray` is a `CComSafeArray<VARIANT>`. It doesn't look like there's a safearray wrapper that naturally interoperates with `_variant_t`, so you need to drop down to raw `VARIANT` level.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thanks for the help. I will take a look at this path and see where it leads. I was wondering if I would need to do something like that approach. While working with the MFC example at one point I had my own wrapper for `VARIANT` until I realized that MFC had some classes that were much nicer and hopefully more bullet proof than my work.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, what I am looking into is making the the `CDBsafeArray` class derive from `tagVARIANT` then using the `CComSafeArray<VARIANT>` to create a member in the `CDBsafeArray` class, `m_SafeArray`. Then I modify the `tagVARIANT` part of the `CDBsafeArray` class to look like an array of VARIANT with `vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;` and `parray = m_SafeArray.m_psa;` which is causing the `CDBsafeArray` object to look like a SAFEARRAY of VARIANTS. This is working fine with my limited example however I suspect there would be problems with something more complicated than what I am doing.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik what I am thinking I really need is to have a conversion operator which would do a lazy evaluation and create the `tagVARIANT` representation using the `CComSafeArray<VARIANT>` data at the time the conversion operator is invoked. That way should the `CComSafeArray<VARIANT>` member change, only the latest version would be presented by the conversion operator.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have posted an answer. Could you review it and let me know if there are any egregious errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**A Brief Overview of Microsoft `VARIANT` and `SAFEARRAY`**

The `VARIANT` type is used to create a variable that may contain a value of many different types. Such a variable may be assigned an integer value at one point and a string value at another. ADO uses `VARIANT` with a number of different methods so that the values read from a database or written to a database can be provided to the caller through a standard interface rather than trying to have lots of different, data type specific interfaces.

Microsoft specifies the `VARIANT` type which is represented as a C/C++ `struct` which contains a number of fields. The two primary parts of this `struct` are a field that contains a value representing the type of the current value stored in the `VARIANT` and a union of the various value types supported by a `VARIANT`.

In addition to `VARIANT` another useful type is `SAFEARRAY`. A `SAFEARRAY` is an array which contains array management data, data about the array such as how many elements it contains, its dimensions, and the upper and lower bounds (the bounds data allows you to have arbitrary index ranges).

The C/C++ source code for a `VARIANT` looks something like the following (all of the component `struct` and `union` members seem to be anonymous, e.g. `__VARIANT_NAME_2` is `#defined` to be empty):

```
typedef struct tagVARIANT VARIANT;

struct tagVARIANT
    {
    union 
        {
        struct __tagVARIANT
            {
            VARTYPE vt;
            WORD wReserved1;
            WORD wReserved2;
            WORD wReserved3;
            union 
                {
                LONGLONG llVal;
                LONG lVal;
                BYTE bVal;
                SHORT iVal;
//  ... lots of other fields in the union
            }   __VARIANT_NAME_2;
        DECIMAL decVal;
        }   __VARIANT_NAME_1;
    } ;
```

COM uses the `VARIANT` type in COM object interfaces to provide the ability to pass data through the interface back and forth and doing any kind of data transformation needed (marshaling).

The `VARIANT` type supports a large variety of data types one of which is `SAFEARAY`. So you can use a `VARIANT` to pass a `SAFEARRAY` over an interface. Rather than having an explicit `SAFEARRAY` interface you can instead specify a `VARIANT` interface that will recognize and process a `VARIANT` that contains a `SAFEARRAY`.

There are several functions provided to manage the `VARIANT` type some of which are:

```
VariantInit()
VariantClear()
VariantCopy()
```

And there are several functions provided to manage the `SAFEARRAY` type some of which are:

```
SafeArrayCreate()
SafeArrayCreateEx()
SafeArrayCopyData();
```

**Three different Microsoft `VARIANT` classes: MFC, ATL, Native C++**

Microsoft has provided several different frameworks over the years and one of the goals of these frameworks and libraries has been the ability to work easily with COM objects.

We will look at three different versions of VARIANT classes for C++ in the following: (1) MFC, (2) ATL, and (3) what Microsoft calls native C++.

MFC is a complex framework developed early in the C++ life to provide a very comprehensive library for Windows C++ programmers.

ATL is a simpler framework developed to assist people creating COM based software components.

The `_variant_t` seems to be a standard C++ class wrapper for `VARIANT`.

The ADO `_RecordsetPtr` class has the `Update()` method that accepts a `_variant_t` object which looks like:

```
inline HRESULT Recordset15::Update ( const _variant_t & Fields, const _variant_t & Values ) {
    HRESULT _hr = raw_Update(Fields, Values);
    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _hr;
}
```

MFC provides a set of classes for working with COM objects with the classes for the `VARIANT` type being `COleVariant` and `COleSafeArray`. If we look at the declaration for these two classes we see the following:

```
class COleVariant : public tagVARIANT
{
// Constructors
public:
    COleVariant();

    COleVariant(const VARIANT& varSrc);
//   .. the rest of the class declaration
};

class COleSafeArray : public tagVARIANT
{
//Constructors
public:
    COleSafeArray();
    COleSafeArray(const SAFEARRAY& saSrc, VARTYPE vtSrc);
//  .. the rest of the class declaration
};
```

If we look at the ATL versions of these classes what we find is `CComVariant` and `CComSafeArray` however `CComSafeArray` is a C++ template. When you declare a variable with `CComSafeArray` you specify the type of the values to be contained in the underlying `SAFEARRAY` structure. The declarations look like:

```
class CComVariant : public tagVARIANT
{
// Constructors
public:
    CComVariant() throw()
    {
        // Make sure that variant data are initialized to 0
        memset(this, 0, sizeof(tagVARIANT));
        ::VariantInit(this);
    }
//  .. other CComVariant class stuff
};

// wrapper for SAFEARRAY.  T is type stored (e.g. BSTR, VARIANT, etc.)
template <typename T, VARTYPE _vartype = _ATL_AutomationType<T>::type>
class CComSafeArray
{
public:
// Constructors
    CComSafeArray() throw() : m_psa(NULL)
    {
    }
    // create SAFEARRAY where number of elements = ulCount
    explicit CComSafeArray(
        _In_ ULONG ulCount,
        _In_ LONG lLBound = 0) : m_psa(NULL)
    {
// .... other CComSafeArray class declaration/definition
};
```

The _variant_t class is declared as follows:

```
class _variant_t : public ::tagVARIANT {
public:
    // Constructors
    //
    _variant_t() throw();

    _variant_t(const VARIANT& varSrc) ;
    _variant_t(const VARIANT* pSrc) ;
//  .. other _variant_t class declarations/definition
};
```

So what we see is a small difference between how the three different frameworks (MFC, ATL, and native C++) do `VARIANT` and `SAFEARRAY`.

**Using the Three `VARIANT` Classes Together**

All three have a class to represent a `VARIANT` which is derived from the `struct tagVARIANT` which allows all three to be used interchangeable across interfaces. *The difference is how each handles a `SAFEARRAY`.* The MFC framework provides `COleSafeArray` which derives from `struct tagVARIANT` and wraps the `SAFEARRAY` library. The ATL framework provides `CComSafeArray` which does not derive from `struct tagVARIANT` but instead uses composition rather than inheritance.

The `_variant_t` class has a set of constructors which will accept a `VARIANT` or a pointer to a `VARIANT` as well as operator methods for assignment and conversion that will accept a `VARIANT` or pointer to a `VARIANT`.

These `_variant_t` methods for `VARIANT` work with the ATL `CComVariant` class and with the MFC `COleVariant` and `COleSafeArray` classes because these are all derived from `struct tagVARIANT` which is `VARIANT`. However the ATL `CComSafeArray` template class does not work well with `_variant_t` because it does not inherit from `struct tagVARIANT`.

For C++ this means that a function that takes an argument of `_variant_t` can be used with the ATL `CComVariant` or with the MFC `COleVariant` and `COleSafeArray` but can not be used with an ATL `CComSafeArray`. Doing so will generate a compiler error such as:

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "const ATL::CComSafeArray<VARIANT, (VARTYPE)12U>" to "const _variant_t" exists
```

See [User-Defined Type Conversions (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwywka61.aspx) in the Microsoft Developer Network documentation for an explanation.

The simplest work around for a `CComSafeArray` seems to be to define a class that derives from `CComSafeArray` and to then provide a method that will provide a `VARIANT` object that wraps the `SAFEARRAY` object of the `CComSafeArray` inside of a `VARIANT`.

```
struct CDBsafeArray: public CComSafeArray<VARIANT>
{
    int                     m_size;
    HRESULT                 m_hr;

    CDBsafeArray(int nSize = 0) : m_size(nSize), m_hr(0)
    {
        // if a size of number of elements greater than zero specified then
        // create the SafeArray which will start out empty.
        if (nSize > 0) m_hr = this->Create(nSize);
    }

    HRESULT CreateOneDim(int nSize)
    {
        // remember the size specified and create the SAFEARRAY
        m_size = nSize;
        m_hr = this->Create(nSize);
        return m_hr;
    }

    // create a VARIANT representation of the SAFEARRAY for those
    // functions which require a VARIANT rather than a CComSafeArray<VARIANT>.
    // this is to provide a copy in a different format and is not a transfer
    // of ownership.
    VARIANT CreateVariant() const {
        VARIANT  m_variant = { 0 };            // the function VariantInit() zeros out so just do it.
        m_variant.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;  // indicate we are a SAFEARRAY containing VARIANTs
        m_variant.parray = this->m_psa;        // provide the address of the SAFEARRAY data structure.
        return m_variant;                      // return the created VARIANT containing a SAFEARRAY.
    }
};
```

This class would then be used to contain the field names and the values for those fields and the ADO `_RecordsetPtr` method of `Update()` would be called like:

```
m_hr = m_pRecordSet->Update(saFields.CreateVariant(), saValues.CreateVariant());
```

Comment: One problem with the `CDBsafeArray` class inheriting from `CComSafeArray<VARIANT>` is that the `CComSafeArray` destructor is not virtual.

Comment: Reading over [Is extending a base class with non-virtual destructor dangerous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597116/is-extending-a-base-class-with-non-virtual-destructor-dangerous) using [free functions rather than trivial extension of a class without a `virtual` destructor](https://punchlet.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/letter-the-fifth/). This would seem to be a better approach so let me make a change to my answer.